# asp.net c# open new window with html that's inside variable

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have asp.net application which queries database and as result gets full email content inside variable.

example of beggining of email:

```
"<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd\"><html xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml\" style=\"margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;box-sizing: border-box;font-size: 13px\"><head style=\"margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;box-sizing: border-box;font-size: 13px\">\n    <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width\" style=\"margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans-serif;box-sizing: border-box;font-size: 13px\">\n    <meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" style=\"margin: 0;padding: 0;font-family: Calibri, Arial, sans
```

And so on... 
I need some way to open a new window and populate that window to show that exact email. 
I am using javascript but fails (i guess) at encoding:

```
    $('#viewEmail').on('click', function () {
    var win = window.open("", "Email", "toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, width=800, height=200, top=" + (screen.height - 400) + ", left=" + (screen.width - 800));
    win.document.body.innerHTML = "@Model.mailBody";
});
```

EDIT:
so the problem is that the hmtl string contained "\n" which translated in line breaks which didn't fit in javacript variable. Solution:

```
@Html.Raw(Model.mailBody.Replace("\n", string.Empty))
```

Comment: Have you tried using `Html.Raw` for the mailBody content?

Comment: yes, i tried "@Html.Raw(model.mailbody)" but javascript still complains about characters

Comment: how about '@Html.Raw(model.mailBody)' with single quotes ..?

Comment: @Sam.C - it doesn't work with single quotes

Comment: what is the error you are getting with it? is it a javascript syntax error? if so what exactly does it say?

Comment: @Sam.C problem was that variable had "\n" which translated in line breaks and that was problem for javascript. solution 
@Html.Raw(Model.mailBody.Replace("\n", string.Empty))